# Commands out of sync in A correct code

Tags: php, mysql

I've the following query executed via PHP, it used to work like yesterday, and stopped working today, here's it :

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT IF (pro.uid= '4342','True','False') FROM pro) AS 'uid' 
FROM 
    Episodes, pro 
ORDER BY 
    Episodes.id DESC 
LIMIT 9
```

The '`4342`' is changed with GET param, I'm having the following error :

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

My PHP API is as the following ( snippets ) :

```
<?php 
include_once "db_config.php"; 

DEFINE ('DB_HOST', $host); 
DEFINE ('DB_USER', $user);      
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', $pass); 
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', $database); 

$mysqli = @($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,  DB_USER,  DB_PASSWORD)) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL'); 
@((bool)mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "USE " . constant('DB_NAME'))) OR die ('Could not select the database'); 

?> 

<?php 

 if(isset($_GET['meaE'], $_GET['uid']))
    { 
         $query="SELECT * , (SELECT  IF (pro.uid=    '".$_GET['uid']."','True','False') FROM pro ) AS 'uid' FROM Episodes,pro  ORDER   BY Episodes.id DESC LIMIT 9
";             
          $resouter = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $query); 

} 

$set = array(); 

$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($resouter); 
if($total_records >= 1){ 

  while ($link = mysqli_fetch_array($resouter,  MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 

    $set['APITest'][] = $link; 
  } 
} 
 echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set)); 
 ?>
```

I want to have the following output :

```
    TABLE A       -  TABLE B 
ID NAME TEXT  UID -   Check_ID
```

The query I want :

Select * From Table A, Check if "134123123" is exists in B, if yes / no add a record for all the taken records from Table A with the value of checking (True/False) .

What's happening with @sagi query is :

There are 3 records in Table B, and 10 records in Table A, when the query is executed, the result is 30 records, each record in Table B has 10 records from Table A, and the "uid" record value is True where the uid is '134123123', and it's false where it's not '134123123' .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query seems wrong, I don't know how it worked yesterday, but right now your are cross joining with out a condition (could be correct but I doubt it) - that means each record in `episodes` will be joined to each record in `pro` . In addition, your subquery with the `IF` will return more then 1 record unless this table contains only 1 record (which again - I doubt it) .

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct t.*, IF (s.uid is null,'True','False')  AS 'uid'
FROM Episodes t
Left JOIN pro s
 ON(s.uid = '4342') 
ORDER BY t.id DESC
LIMIT ?????
```

Try using a sub query instead of a join:

```
Select t.*,
       Case when exists(select 1 from pro s where s.uid = '4342')
            Then 'true' else 'false' 
       End as 'uid'
From episodes t
Order by t.id desc
Limit 9;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you saved me!, it stopped working after i've added a new column to the pro table, don't know why it was working before, seems i need to re-check mysql again. thanks again :) .

Comment: I'm having a problem with this query, the records are getting duplicated, i've like 3 records in "pro" and 10 in "Episodes", so it's 3x10, each record in pro is getting 10 records from Episodes.

Comment: Replace the `CommonColumn` with the relation, and add change the `SELECT ..` to `SELECT DISTINCT ..`

Comment: Explain : even with the "ON" and DISTINCT, it still show only 2 records, i need the mentioned record via 'uid", i wanna check if the uid is in that table, then make them all True, which was working in the old query .

Comment: Mate? after check the query you got me wrong, i want all the records in Episodes, and for each record in Episodes, i want to add a new record "uid", its value depends if the uid is found in pro.uid record .

Comment: Still the same, btw there is no relation between "pro" table and "Episodes" table via the id or anything else, I've edited my post to make things clear .

Comment: Something wrong is happening, when i'm doing that query, it's not checking for the specific "UID" the given in the query, it duplicates the records for all the records in UID, so it's 3x10, and the "uid" new record is true for the give "UID" and false if it's not exist .

Comment: I'm in the middle of something, I'll check why this is happening in about an hour

Comment: Did you finish yet ? :P

Comment: Both versions should work, now I could understand you, try to explain it like this next time.

Comment: The second one worked, the first one still has the same duplication problem.